# Sending Message to a iFrame using postMessage from parent?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to send a postMessage to a iFrame from the parent window? I know how you can send from the iFrame to the parent, I need to send a response message after the parent receives it.

EDIT---------------
I have the following.

```
Parent Window:
function toFrame(type, data) {
    $("iframe[data-atdl='schedule']").contentWindow.postMessage({
        type: type,
        data: data
    }, "*");
}
```

iFrame:

```
window.addEventListener("message", fromParent, false);

function fromParent(e) {
        var data = e.data.data;
        var type = e.data.type;

        sendParentData("ALERT","Action " + type + " :: " + data);
    }
```

~Z

Comment: Note: It is cross-domain.

Comment: Yes, it works both ways.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara How do you select the iFrame from the parent? I have the following... (updated)

Comment: `contentWindow` is not a property of a jQuery collection, you probably want `$("iframe[data-atdl='schedule']")[0].contentWindow`